# Выведет ли Hello, World!?

Tags: c++

Гарантировано ли стандартом, что этот код выведет в консоль (устройство вывода - консоль, а не какое-то другое) следующую строку?

> Hello, World!

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!";
}
```

Comment: А откуда вообще такие вопросы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартные классы потоков ввода-вывода языка С++ [ассоциируют объекты со стандартными потоками языка С](http://eel.is/c++draft/iostream.objects#overview-2). И, соответственно, наследуют их свойства.

Спецификация стандартных потоков языка С говорит, что в зависимости от реализации, последняя строка текстового потока может требовать (или не требовать) наличия символа "новой строки" в конце последней строки потока. В тех реализациях, в которых такое требование присутствует, незавершенная последняя строка не является частью потока.

Попросту выражаясь, с педантично-формальной точки зрения, будет ли эта программа что-то выводить определяется реализацией.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что значит "ассоциирует": будут вызываться объекты, описанные стандартом `C`, или просто синхронизация с ними?

Comment: @level Я так понимаю, что имеется в виду, что С++ объекты являются надстройками/оболочками над С потоками. Имеется ли в виду, что они обязаны работать именно через stdin/stdout, или просто хотели сказать, что они просто наследуют общее поведение - не знаю навскидку. Хотя следующий пункт стандарта вроде бы подразумевает буквальную ассоциацию с stdin/stdout.

Comment: А про отсутствие return 0

Comment: @dreamIIx `return 0;` в `main` предполагается, если его явно не указано.